# Why C++ doesn't take correct value in a loop?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to find prime numbers and for that I do:

```
int main() {
/* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */

int count;
cin >> count;

for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    int num, num2;
    cin >> num;
    num2 = num;
    int res = 1;

    while(num > 1) {
        for(int j = 2; j < static_cast<int>(sqrt(num) + 0.5); j++) {
            int a = num2 % j;
            if(a == 0) {
                res = res * j;
                num2 = num2 / j;
                //cout << j << endl;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "Result is: " << res << endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

but I do not know why, when I enter `315` it prints me: `3 5 3`, without `7`. But when I paste `17` instead of `static_cast<int>(sqrt(num) - 0.5)` that gives me 17, too, it prints the `7`, as well.

So, what is the problem, that when I type 17 it prints me 7, but when I calculate with sqrt - it doesn't?

Also, it does not print  this one `cout << "Result is: " << res << endl;`.

I did not work with C++ for a long time, so may be I forgot something?

Comment: Try to print `num`, `j` and `static_cast<int>(sqrt(num) - 0.5)` in each for loop turn and see what happens.

Comment: Step through with a debugger, and the problem will be obvious.  The code gets into an infinite loop, since `num` reduces to a value of 7, but the loop never encounters a value of `a == 0` then.

Comment: Why are you subtracting 0.5? If your number is 49 you will only try up to 6. You should be adding 0.5.

Comment: You can avoid working with floats if you change the comparison to `j * j <= num`.  The other issues are addressed in the comments.

Comment: @Peter but why when I type 17 it works, but sqrt does not??? =/

Comment: @stark in this case I get 18, not 17

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This program attempts to factor a number. Whenever the number hits 1, it has been fully factorized. So the loop should be `while (num>1)`.

Furthermore, you fail to extract powers of primes. You will get 2 and 4 if num is 8. This is solvable if you replace the "`int a=num%j;if(a==0)`" lines with `while (num % j == 0)`. You'd get the same prime repeatedly, sure [that can be fixed too if you wish].

Alright, I have actually introduced an important performance problem to gain correctness. But can we regain the performance?

You can add an additional condition in the for loop: `if (j * j > num) {cout<<num; num=1;}`

In the comments, the OP says he wants to obtain all prime factors and ... multiply them together? I'll write code that handles one number below:

```
int num, res = 1;
cin >> num;
for (int d = 2; d <= num; d++)
{
    while(num % d == 0) //while also acts as if
    {
        cout << d << " ";
        num = num / d; //or num /= d;
        res = res * d; //or res *= d;
    }
}
//here num is 1, res is the original number and the prime factors have been printed
```

Comment: No, it still does not print `7` =/

Comment: @Doe Well, then the for should use `j<num` instead of `j<sqrt(num)`. This will prevent you from missing the higher primes. Then don't display the final number as you'd display a one.

Comment: The square root actually changes on each iteration (the square root will change as you divide num by each factor). That's why you cannot use the sqrt thing.

Comment: Of course this may be troublesome in case of actual primes. I see no good solution actually.

Comment: @Doe Can you also integrate the new change in my answer to fix the performance problem? If I give you a large prime like 2147483647 you would solve it faster [stop at 65536 rather than continue]

Comment: but why my `cout` does not print in the very bottom? =/

Comment: @Doe Did you actually fix the while loop to be with ">1"?

Comment: @Doe This is actually difficult to see since I don't see how you actually fixed the code.

Comment: @Doe What variable are you testing in the while loop? And you seem not to have obeyed ALL my instructions after all.

Comment: ...just let me write my own version. @Doe

Comment: the number what user entered. Now I'm adding your instructions too

Comment: I have just seen something weirder as I was trying to write my own version. You want to find the largest prime divisor for each of the inputted numbers?

Comment: I need to find all prime factors and multiple them later

Comment: for example for 315 are: 3, 5, 3, 7

Answer (score 1):

`static_cast<int>(sqrt(315) - 0.5)` is equal to `17`, but you are probably dividing `num` by some `j` on the previous iteration of the for loop, here:

```
num = num / j;
```

Comment: I did not get that, is it wrong dividing `num / j` ? =/

Comment: @Doe no, but as you do it you change the result of `static_cast<int>(sqrt(num) + 0.5)` which is evaluated according to the current value of `num` at every iteration of the for loop. This is probably undesired.